# Regex query - for matching everything except string

Tags: azure, regex

I'm trying to match up a regex expression here and I'm hoping for a direction.

I'm trying to ignore matches for the following list but match everything else around this commandline:

```
(?i)/FORMAT:[^(CSV|HFORM|HTABLE|LIST|MOF|RAWXML|TABLE|VALUE|XML)]
```

Can anyone else provide some direction?

To add more to my story: I'm trying to build a regex in Azure Sentinel to match all file extensions except the following list. Azure Sentinel uses Python Regex I believe and for the life of me I can't get it to work correctly.

Answer (score 1):

Just a guess.

```
(?i)\/FORMAT:(?!(?:CSV|HFORM|HTABLE|LIST|MOF|RAWXML|TABLE|VALUE|XML))\w+
```

`?!` means (colon) "not followed by".

`?:` means "don't capture this parenthesis" (makes it maybe a bit faster).

`\w+` means "a word".

https://regex101.com/r/DmQwAa/1

---

Or do you mean something like:

```
(?i)^\S+\s+(?:[\/-]\S+\s+){0,100}[\/-]FORMAT:(?!(?:CSV|HFORM|HTABLE|LIST|MOF|RAWXML|TABLE|VALUE|XML))\S+\s+(?:[\/-]\S+(?:\s+|$)){0,100}$
```

https://regex101.com/r/DmQwAa/3

---

Need more examples from OP.

Comment: Apologies @UAV, see above for more information